# Travelling with controlled substances through Doha, Qatar on a connecting flight?

Tags: transit, legal, qatar-airways, qatar

I just need to fly from Thailand to America and am considering using Qatar Airways. I know the word controlled substance sounds like a bad word so let me just explain in more detail. I have some sleep medicine, just about 4 pills of Lunasta with the prescription on a bottle that is my brother's (same last name). I also bought some Valium (about 4-6 pills) in Thailand that is in it's original packaging, no prescription. These pill woulds be on me, not in checked luggage.

I fly coach only and I plan on using this sleeping medicine to make the 26 hour journey not a sleepless one. I've got a bag of medicine I travel with that has other stuff in it too that would be in checked luggage. Stuff that is not a scheduled control substance but does require a prescription in some countries like ibuprofen and pseudoephedrine. And a lot of allergy medicines. Some with my name on them as a prescription and others not.

My wife suffers from migraines and since we are in Thailand I would like her to go ahead and get a prescription for pain medicines (narcotics) for that in case she has an episode in America. It would be a prescription for about a week's worth of medicine.

Questions/concerns: Will my stuff be confiscated? Will I go to jail? I've heard of the story where there was a young man who had some trace amount of weed in his shoe lace and was put into jail... My alternative is to fly through Japan but it costs about 300-400 dollars more that way for 2 people..

**edit**: and when I say narcotics, I mean clinical narcotics, like vicoden and tramadol. Not like street drugs... that word has some different interpretation.

Comment: Japan is not necessarily going to be easier. "Japanese customs officials have detained travelers carrying prohibited items, sometimes for several weeks"  (from the US Embassy site). Narcotics are prohibited, **even with a prescription** unless an application is made weeks in advance and approved.

Answer (score 8):

You're **probably OK**, but I'd still skip the narcotics and anything you don't have a prescription for.

All the Gulf states, including Qatar, enforce *very* strict drug controls.  Qatar has a [list of all drugs](https://healthcare.qa/drugs-list) you're allowed to bring into the country, and if it's not on there, you can't bring it in even with a prescription.  However...

You're not actually entering Qatar, you're just passing through in transit, which means you're not going to pass through Customs.  Now, there may be a random check of incoming passengers at the gate, but these are rare, and if you have a prescription, aren't entering the country and only have personal use quantities, they are highly unlikely to care.

Also, while it's not the focus of your question, I'd be *very, very* careful about importing narcotics to the US.  If at all possible, you'd probably be better off getting a prescription and buying them in the US after you've arrive.

Comment: So I checked the list. Valium and Tramadol are on that list. I think I'm going to bring my big bag of medicines (allergy pills, stomach pills, etc). And like 1 small prescription for Valium. The only thing I can see going wrong is a bunch of different cold medicines in tablet form (which are not controlled substances) being a problem/holding me up/getting detained for it until they determine if they are legal or not.