# Can I bring these OTC medicines to India from the UK via Doha?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, airport-security, qatar, health

I have read online that some restricted items can cause jail?

I will be travelling by one way

Would these items be ok to take:

Cod liver capsules (3bottles) in checked baggage

Paracetamol hand luggage

Iberogast for digestion  in checked luggage (Iberogast has its ingredients written in German)

Contraceptive pills hand luggage

Protein powder in checked luggage

I don't have prescriptions or doc note as they are over the counter Meds

Thanks

Also if anything Is in hand luggage and should be in checked please let me know also if I can carry something in hand luggage and I have stated checked luggage also let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Those should all be fine**.  None are prescription medicines or have any potential for abuse, so it's fine to transit Qatar with them.  See this question's answers for a list of drugs you *cannot* bring with you: [Travelling with controlled substances through Doha, Qatar on a connecting flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30232/travelling-with-controlled-substances-through-doha-qatar-on-a-connecting-flight)

I presume they're also all solids or powders, so they can all be carried in either hand or checked luggage.

Comment: The Iberogast is a liquid it's for digestion and I'm just worried incase they want to read the ingredients because they are in German and not English it's a 20ml bottle

Comment: 20 ml is well under the 100 ml carry-on limit, so that's also fine.

Comment: Ok the fact that the ingredients are no in english but are in German, would this cause an issue

Comment: Since you're only transiting, all you need to do is pass security, not Customs. And security only cares about the size of the bottle.

Comment: Oh ok and would you happen to know about my destination(india)? Would they say anything about all the items I have mentioned above

Comment: That's another question, but I doubt they would care.